# Can't install packages by a text file with listed names

Tags: bash, pacman

Also I tried with IFS=" " but the result is the same.

```
arch-chroot /mnt
pacman -Sy
echo "most less" > "/root/.testlist.rs"
pacman -S $(cat "/root/.testlist.rs")
# [1] error: target not found: most less
pacman -S $(cat "/root/.testlist.rs" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\s$//')
# [2] error: target not found: most less
pacman -S $(eval echo $(cat "/root/.testlist.rs")
# [3] error: target not found: most less
```

I found out that before these commands were some another which broke this bash session which is running on archiso image:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(cat "/root/.testlist.rs"))
sum=""; for pkg in ${arr[@]}; do sum+=$(echo "$pkg "); done

pacman -S $(echo "$sum")
# error: target not found: zathura-pdf-mupdf zita-alsa-pcmi zita-resampler zlib zsh zsh-syntax-highlighting
pacman -S $(eval echo "$sum")
# error: target not found: zathura-pdf-mupdf zita-alsa-pcmi zita-resampler zlib zsh zsh-syntax-highlighting
```

Comment: All commands are normally working with zsh though.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I just tried `echo "most less" > aa` and `sudo pacman -S $(cat "aa")` and it launched `pacman` and started the installation process for the two packages. Please run `set -x` and then `pacman  -S $(cat "/root/.testlist.rs")` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, the issue you are facing depends on the value of `IFS`.

Given a file containing a sample package list:

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' 'most less' >./.testlist.rs
$ cat ./.testlist.rs 
most less
```

the expansion of `$(cat .testlist.rs)` only results in the two tokens `most` and `less` if `IFS` includes the white space (as it does by default) or if `IFS` is unset.
Otherwise, it results in the single token `most less`, which of course does not correspond to any package name.

Note that variable assignments [affect the current environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) when they are part of a simple command that has no command name, as in `IFS=$'\n' arr=($(cat .testlist.rs))`. Subsequent expansions are hence only split on newlines, meaning that:

- Each `arr`'s element is a whole line from `.testlist.rs`;
- The expansion of each element of `arr` in `for pkg in ${arr[@]}` is not split further;
- The expansion of `$(echo "$sum")` — where `sum`'s content is a single line resulting from the space-separated concatenation of `arr`'s elements — is not split further, again resulting in a single token that is used as a package name.

It seems way more practical to save a list with one package per line:

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' most less >.testlist.rs 
$ cat .testlist.rs 
most
less
```

Then, in Bash, you can easily use `mapfile` (or its synonym `readarray`) to populate an array based on the content of your file:

```bsh
$ mapfile -t arr <.testlist.rs 
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="most" [1]="less")
```

and use it as an argument, as in `pacman -S "${arr[@]}"`.

Finally note that, while `pacman action [options] $(command generating a package list)` is often used in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Main_page), a (really) long list of packages may cause `pacman` to fail with an "argument list too long" error. An alternative that avoids that issue and also plays nicely with a list of packages stored in a file is:

```bsh
<.testlist.rs xargs -o sudo pacman -S
```

where `-o` (`--open-tty`) is required to allow `pacman` to interact with the user.
This actually also works when multiple packages are listed, separated by spaces (or tabs), on the same line of `.testlist.rs` (as in your case).